# Want to add an image with the Title

Tags: graphics, titles

This is my code for the title:

```
\title{ 
        \usefont{OT1}{bch}{b}{n}
        \normalfont \normalsize \textsc{ABC Summer Research Programme} \\ [25pt]
        \horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]
        \huge Compact Riemann Surfaces    \\
        \horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]
}
```

This gives me the text

> ABC Summer Research Programme

in the middle of the page. I want to have the text in the left side of the page and add an image in the right-side empty space and in the next line "Compact Riemann Surfaces" should come.

I tried this:

```
\title{ 
        \usefont{OT1}{bch}{b}{n}
        \normalfont \normalsize \textsc{ABC Summer Research
            Programme\\} \\ [25pt]\begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{tifr_logo}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:abc}
    \end{figure}\horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]
        \huge Compact Riemann Surfaces    \\
        \horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]
}
```

But this just adds the picture at the end of the page (in the left corner). Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest your given code is far away from beeing an [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Please next question add an mwe! It helps us to help you!

Your code has several issues, for example is `\horrule` not defined ...

But the main issue is that you are using `figure`, an environment making your added image floating you simply do not want.

So please see the following mwe (please see commented parts of your code to get rid of floating and your wrong used `\\` causing message `no line here to end`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\title{%
  %\usefont{OT1}{bch}{b}{n}
  \normalfont \normalsize \textsc{ABC Summer Research Programme}
    \\[25pt]%
% \begin{figure} % <==========================================
    \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    %\caption{}
    %\label{fig:abc}
% \end{figure}%  <============================================
% \horrule{0.5pt}  % <========================================
  \\[0.4cm]
  \huge Compact Riemann Surfaces    %\\  % <==================
% \horrule{2pt} 
  \\[0.5cm]
}

\maketitle
text.
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting title]

If I understood you right you can now change the code for the title to get what you want to:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\title{%
  %\usefont{OT1}{bch}{b}{n}
  \normalfont \normalsize \textsc{ABC Summer Research Programme}\hfill 
    \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{example-image-duck}\\[25pt]%
  {\huge Compact Riemann Surfaces}   \\[0.5cm]
}

\maketitle
I want to have the text in the left side of the page and add an image in the right-side empty space and in the next line "Compact Riemann Surfaces" should come. 
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

For your added comment: To have 1 cm less space above the title use the following code (change the value `1cm` for your needs ...):

```
\title{%
  \vspace{-1cm} % <=======================================================
  \normalfont \normalsize \textsc{ABC Summer Research Programme}\hfill 
    \includegraphics[width=0.12\linewidth]{example-image-duck}\\[25pt]%
  {\huge Compact Riemann Surfaces}   \\[0.5cm]
}
```